# Do I get anything for doing things on the checklist?

Tags: kirby-mass-attack

There is a list of secret tasks I can complete in the game. Do I get anything for completely finishing the checklist?

Answer (score 1):

From what it looks like, there isn't too much.

You get one of the Special Shots as a reward for completing it. That's all I could find really...

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ds/609573-kirby-mass-attack/cheats)